# Add values to Web API model using ActionFilter or Custom Model Binder?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm using WebAPI 2 and I'm finding that most of my API POST endpoints are requiring the same two values be added to the model: **UserId** from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() and **SignalR_ConnectionId** from a custom request header.  I'd like to add these two values to the model without repeating the same code within each request handler.

I like the idea of using an ActionFilter because then I can easily decorate the endpoints that need this functionality with the annotation.  So far my ActionFilter looks like the following:

```
public class AddUserIdActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var headerValues = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("SignalRId");

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null)
        {
            Guid userId = Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }

        //Modify the model??
    }
}
```

How do I modify the model within the ActionFilter?  (I assume that each model that is decorated with the attribute would descend from a base class with a property for userId and SignalRId).

If I can't add the values to the model, I'll have to consider a Custom Model Binder.  I don't want to change the default model binding, just add my two properties to what's already happening. How do I approach this in Web API 2?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked fine.

```
public class AddUserIdActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> headers;
        string connectionId;
        Guid userId;

        if(actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("SignalR_Id", out headers))
        {
            connectionId = headers.First();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        }

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null)
        {
            userId = Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }

        try
        {
            var model = (BaseCommand)actionContext.ActionArguments.Values.First();
            model.UserId = userId;
            model.ConnectionId = connectionId;
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));
        }
    }

}
```